# Android listview overlaps adview

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

In my `xml` I have a `listview` and an `adview (admob)`.

If I put the `adview` at the top everything it fine, but if I put it at the bottom, below the `listview` it vanishes.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

        <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
    </com.google.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the layout weight of your listview:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'weight' in package 'android'

Comment: Fixed. Should be `layout_weight`.

Comment: Actually, I think the `layout_height` should be 0 instead of `wrap_content`. Might work as is though. Giving it (and no other siblings) a layout_weight tells it to additionally take the remainder of space available after all the layout_heights are calculated.